# Passing an Empty Value of Array and Counts the value inside it.

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have this certain code that checks if a variable is **not empty** if it is not empty 
it will merge in an array that "has" a value in it. if it is empty it will merge in an array but passing "no values or any other stuff even null values"

Here my code for it.

```
$fb_description_arr[] = ($page_desc != "") ? $page_desc : array();
$fb_share_arr[] = ($share_link != "") ? $share_link : array();
$tweet_arr[] = ($twitter_link != "") ? $twitter_link : array();
$follow_arr[] = ($twitter_follow != "") ? $twitter_follow : array();
$site_link_arr[] = ($site_link != "") ? $site_link : array();
```

Let's say **$page_desc is not null**, and has a value of "This is me" and the **rest of the variables are null**

```
$test_arr = array_merge($fb_description_arr, $fb_share_arr, $tweet_arr, $follow_arr, $site_link_arr);
print_r($test_arr);
```

so I tried to debug and show the merged array on it. that will be shown below.

**Array ( [0] => This is me[1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) [3] => Array ( ) [4] => Array ( ) )**

So if I count it up using the count() function in php

```
$total_raffle = count(array_merge($fb_description_arr, $fb_share_arr, $tweet_arr, $follow_arr, $site_link_arr));
```

Obviously, it will show an output of **"5"**

What solutions I've tried in ternary operator to pass an empty value that will not be counted in count() function.

1. array()
2. null
3. false
4. ""

So my desired output is **"1"** since **$page_desc is the only variable that has value in it** and the rest doesn't have any value

Any solutions for this stuff?

A help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution I can think of for your problem is to get away from the ternaries and use the side-effect of assignment to append values to $test_arr:

```
<?php

$page_desc = "This is me";
$share_link = $twitter_link = $twitter_follow = $site_link = '';

if ($page_desc !== "")  {
    $test_arr[] = $fb_description_arr[] = $page_desc;
}

if ($share_link !== "")  {
    $test_arr[] = $fb_share_arr[] = $share_link;
}

if ($twitter_link !== "")  {
    $test_arr[] = $tweet_arr[] = $twitter_link;
}

if ($twitter_follow !== "")  {
    $test_arr[] = $follow_arr[] = $twitter_follow;
}

if ($site_link !== "")  {
    $test_arr[] = $site_link_arr[] = $site_link;
}


var_dump($test_arr, count($test_arr));
```

(Note that this code assumes that a bunch of variables with empty arrays in them is not something your later code is expecting to find)

Comment: Yeah, that's the first thing I did, just wanted to shorten my line of codes though. I guess I don't have any choice on it. Thanks for your answer. :)